# java GWT download for net beans/eclipse

Tags: gwt

I want to download gwt plugin for netbeans/eclipse.
can anyone help me out with any site or guide me that how it will happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link of GWT plugin for Eclipse [Eclipse GWT Plugin](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/download.html)

For NetBeans 
[GWT4NB](https://gwt4nb.dev.java.net/)

Comment: Also for Netbeans you'll need to download the SDK separately and configure the plugin properly.

Answer (score 0):

With GWT 2.2 you can generate project with webAppCreator from GWT SDK with -maven option. Maven projects work pretty well in Netbeans. It might be an option for you.